# How to open a opened tab (old tab) in chrome using Notification onclick?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, notifications

I use Notification on click to open a opened tab, but not success. In my case when i click a notification, it open a new tab, i want to open a old tab i has open.

Comment: You should post the code whatever you have done. If you need help then take some time to post the question with all adequate information which helps people to understand the problem.

Comment: do you want to open the last tab you closed? like CTRL + SHIFT + T?, quite hard to understand tbh...

Comment: SORRY, I newbie in stackoverflow :(. I post some new info about my question below, can you read to help me, pls!

Answer (score 0):

It' s possible in javascript.

```
//You can open new tab like this
var openedTab = window.open('Your URL', '_blank');

//You can return that tab like this
openedTab.focus();
```

Comment: hmmm...It open a new tab, i want open a old tab i has opened. thank you!